# Merge command DB2 AIX (Update ok, insert not ok)

Tags: merge, db2

I'm currently struggeling with the merge command on a AIX DB2 9.7.
All I want to achieve is write a command which performes and Update when there is already a row with the primary keys checked and if not, then perform the Insert statement.
That is what I expect the merge command can be used for.

Select  something
   if exists then update 
   if not exists then isert

The Update statements works (I can see in my Toad) and of course in the database e.g. timestamp. But the Insert doesn't work.
Threre no syntay error shown, but no insert is made. Toad shows "executed successfully".

Any help is appreciated.
The WHERE clause shows the primary keys of the table.

```
    MERGE INTO DSPTMCP.KENNZAHL_DEFINITION as KD
USING(Select NR_MANDANT, SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL, SL_KENNZAHL
FROM DSPTMCP.KENNZAHL_DEFINITION
WHERE NR_MANDANT = 5472 AND SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL = '_VBH' AND SL_KENNZAHL = 104) as KD1
ON(KD.NR_MANDANT = KD1.NR_MANDANT AND KD.SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL = KD1.SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL AND KD.SL_KENNZAHL = KD1.SL_KENNZAHL)
WHEN MATCHED Then
UPDATE SET
BEZ_KENNZAHL_ABS = 'MEFGA',
BEZ_KENNZAHL_REL = 'Aufgaben',
BEZ_EINHEIT_ABS = '%',
BEZ_EINHEIT_REL = '%',
SL_MODIFIZIERUNG = 3,
ANZ_NACHKOMMASTELLEN_ABS = 2,
ANZ_NACHKOMMASTELLEN_REL = 2,
KZ_QUALITAETSZIEL_ABS = 'H',
KZ_QUALITAETSZIEL_REL = 'H',
BEZ_ERMITTLUNGSFREQUENZ = 'Monatl.',
BEZ_ERMITTLUNGSART = 'Automat',
BEZ_DATENLIEFERANT = 'Geschäftsfelddaten',
TXT_QUELLINFORMATION = 'Geschäftsfelddaten',
TXT_KNZ_BESCHREIBUNG = 'Aufgaben',
FAK_REF_GEWICHT = 1,
KZ_HILFSGROESSE = 'N',
SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL_REL = 'ALLG',
SL_KENNZAHL_REL = 10,
FAK_ERGEBNIS_REL = 1,
BEZ_EINHEIT_QUELLE = '%',
FAK_UMRECHNUNG_QUELLE = 1,
KZ_REF_OHNE_VORZEICHEN = 'N'
WHEN Not MATCHED Then
INSERT (NR_MANDANT,
SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL,
SL_KENNZAHL,
SYS_DWH_TSP,
SL_MODIFIZIERUNG,
UID_ERFASSUNG,
TSP_ERFASSUNG,
UID_AENDERUNG,
TSP_AENDERUNG,
BEZ_EINHEIT_ABS,
ANZ_NACHKOMMASTELLEN_ABS,
SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL_REF,
SL_KENNZAHL_REF,
KZ_REF_OHNE_VORZEICHEN,
SL_REF_VERDICHTUNG,
BEZ_KENNZAHL_ABS,
BEZ_KENNZAHL_REL,
KZ_HIERARCHIESUMME,
KZ_QUALITAETSZIEL_ABS,
KZ_QUALITAETSZIEL_REL,
BEZ_ERMITTLUNGSFREQUENZ,
BEZ_ERMITTLUNGSART,
IHT_MINIMAL,
IHT_MAXIMAL,
IHT_MINIMAL_REL,
IHT_MAXIMAL_REL,
BEZ_DATENLIEFERANT,
TXT_QUELLINFORMATION,
DAT_ERFASSUNG_AB,
DAT_ERFASSUNG_BIS,
TXT_KNZ_BESCHREIBUNG,
FAK_REF_GEWICHT,
KZ_HILFSGROESSE,
SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL_REL,
SL_KENNZAHL_REL,
FAK_ERGEBNIS_REL,
BEZ_EINHEIT_QUELLE,
FAK_UMRECHNUNG_QUELLE,
BEZ_EINHEIT_REL,
ANZ_NACHKOMMASTELLEN_REL)
VALUES(5472,
'_VBH',
'104',
current timestamp,
3,
'AUTOMAT',
current timestamp,
'AUTOMAT',
current timestamp,
'%',
2,
null,
null,
'N',
null,
'Aufgaben',
'Aufgaben',
'N',
'H',
'H',
'Monatl.',
'Automat',
null,
null,
null,
null,
'Geschäftsfelddaten',
'Geschäftsfelddaten',
'01.01.2000',
'31.12.9999',
'Aufgaben',
1,
'N',
'ALLG',
'10',
1,
'%',
1,
'%',
2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The target table coming from the using clause needn't to be empty.
Switched it to sysdummy and now it works.

Something like this

```
MERGE INTO DSPTMCP.KENNZAHL_DEFINITION as KD
USING(Select 5472 AS NR_MANDANT, '_KCR' AS SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL, 
600 AS SL_KENNZAHL FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) as KD1
ON(KD.NR_MANDANT = KD1.NR_MANDANT AND KD.SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL = KD1.SL_GRUPPE_KENNZAHL AND KD.SL_KENNZAHL = KD1.SL_KENNZAHL)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
```